# Dot inserted on EPUB doc with Calibre

Tags: calibre, chapters

I am converting an Open Office Doc into EPUB with Calibre and everything works great, except in front of every Chapter Heading in the body of the doc, Calibre adds a single dot. I am using the tag "Heading 1" in Open Office.  In the image below you can see the dot to the left of the Chapter title.  Is there a way to get rid of this?  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Odds are that during the conversion process the 'heading' tag is getting that 'dot' style added. Try adding "list-style: none;" in the CSS code as follows:   

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {list-style: none;}

Comment: Thank you.  Where would I find this stylesheet?  I looked in 4 different stylesheets but found not reference to h1 or h2 tags.  Thanks again for the help.  I'm using win 11.

Comment: In OpenOffice [OO] you seem to have 'Bullets' added to the 'header1' line.  In OO under the 'paragraph options' on the right panel remove it from the 'header1' by unclicking it. The CSS stylesheet is accessible from within Calibre "after" you imported it there. I test opened a Jane Austen ebook in Calibre (and looked at its internal code) and they have 2 minimal sized CSS stylesheets (with things like 'calibre1), while the ... h1, h2, etc., are all located on the actual page. Note: h1 = header1 = calibre1, these are just different CSS naming methods for the same thing when styling an ebook.

Answer (score 0):

I doubled checked my OO doc and I don't see any bullets in the Header unless somehow they are masked?  I finally went into the code in calibre and deleted the extraneous LI tags and now it looks great.  Thank you for the help!
[image]

Comment: Good catch! That was going to be my next suggestion <ol> <li> tags.